# file_get_contents() failing. PHP

Tags: php

The following two lines of code work. They save the data from [here](https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/YAHOO/INDEX_VIX.json) and [here](https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/MOODY/DAAAYLD.json) down successfully. I can see the files on my server.

```
file_put_contents("vix.json", fopen("https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/YAHOO/INDEX_VIX.json?api_key=example", 'r'));
file_put_contents("aaa.json", fopen("https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/MOODY/DAAAYLD.json?api_key=example", 'r'));
```

I can pull data successfully from the first file using this:

```
$v = file_get_contents("vix.json");
```

But the following is stopping my PHP script:

```
$a = file_get_contents("aaa.json");
```

I comment out the above line and the script runs, include it and it fails.

Error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$a' (T_VARIABLE)
```

Work in progress. Currently googling this error. Any de-bug pointers/suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Well, check the logs.

Comment: my error handler isnt triggered. Which logs?

Comment: Turned on error reporting? `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);` at the top of your script. Then post your error messages/notices here so we can help better, because `"failing"` isn't descriptive enough to help anyone.

Comment: The logs should be in /var/log/apache2/error.log
If it is run by apache and on linux.
And enable error reporting in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini.

Comment: ok thanks, 5 mins - ill post an update

Comment: Alright, can you show all of the code, because you're missing a `;` somewhere before you define the `$a` variable.

Comment: found it. Apologies, been looking at this too long. If you wanna put that last comment as an answer, will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always the tiny little issues that you could face that are the hardest ones. For future reference while developing, always have error reporting turned on so that you can pick up errors like this.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

Which led to your error, meaning you were missing a semi-colon(`;`) somewhere before you defined your `$a` variable.